# Building web pages with pl/sql

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to figure out how to develop web pages with pl/slq and I have some code that I found.  My issue with this is where do I get the output? As far as I can tell after I compile the code and run the script there are no problems.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE list_tables IS
    CURSOR cur_tables IS
       SELECT table_name
       FROM   user_tables
       ORDER BY table_name;
 BEGIN
    HTP.HTMLOPEN;
    HTP.HEADOPEN;
    HTP.TITLE('Display a List');
    HTP.HEADCLOSE;
    HTP.BODYOPEN;
    HTP.ULISTOPEN;
       FOR cur_tables_rec IN cur_tables LOOP
          HTP.LISTITEM(cur_tables_rec.table_name);
       END LOOP;
    HTP.ULISTCLOSE;
    HTP.BODYCLOSE;
    HTP.HTMLCLOSE;
 END list_tables;
 /
```

Comment: At this low level normally you'd set up a PL/SQL web gateway to listen for calls to `list_tables` and execute your procedure, as per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_we.htm. But in your case I'd recommend considering Oracle Application Express instead, so you don't have to write code like this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing (or have access to) SQL*Developer  you can access the htp.xxx() output from the "OWA output" window (ie View -> OWA Output)

if you open that window and connect it to your session then from an SQL worksheet

```
exec list_tables();
```

you should see your output similar to below with your tables listed

```
Content-type: text/html
Content-length: 19899

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Display a List</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<UL>
... etc ...
</UL>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```